# Xcode organizer documentation, show Table of Contents

Tags: xcode, organizer

I know this can be done, as I've done it before - but I can't remember how, and I've searched and can't find how either.

I want the Xcode organiser documentation to show the 'table of contents', just as it does if you load the API docs in a web browser. They are hidden by default, and there is a command I can execute to make it visible.

Anybody know what it is?

Thanks

(The bit on the left of my screen shot)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Xcode 4.3:

```
sudo egrep -lRZ "Prototype.Browser.Xcode4OrNewer=Prototype.Browser.XcodeVersion<1000;" ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets | xargs -0 -L % sudo sed -i '' -e 's/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=Prototype\.Browser\.XcodeVersion\<1000\;/Prototype\.Browser\.Xcode4OrNewer\=false\;/g'
```

..and your documentation will now look like this:

[image]

Not for everyone, but I like it.

Comment: I will. Got to wait 2 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Eye" tab on the left side. Or you can also use the jump bar (or what it's called) in the middle, below the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. I'll update my post with a screen shot of what I want... the table of contents..

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't available in the newer versions (since XCode 4?) of the documentation browser. They removed it in favor for the jump bar I think. Maybe you could try the 3rd party documentation browser Ingredients (http://fileability.net/ingredients/). It has a nice table of contents and function list on the right side.

Comment: It is available. I was using a month ago on an iMac i was using on a contract, but I didn't make a note of how i did it. Now i don't have access to that machine anymore. The content page is the same web page - it's probably just some style sheet that hides it when it's displayed in organiser.

Comment: I figured it out. I've put my answer above.